# How to turn a text to speech by clicking on it on blogger

Tags: javascript

I am new to web development. I have recently created a blog on blogger CMS and I am trying to write a code that turns a text to audio when the user clicks on it. I tried the below code on w3schools / codepen websites, it worked fine. but when I used it in my blog's post it did not work. Can you advice what is wrong.

```
<audio id="write">
<source src="https://elc101files.000webhostapp.com/write.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element
</audio>
    <a href='#'>
<p onclick="playAudio()" >Write</p>
    </a>
<script type="text/javascript">
var x = document.getElementById("write");
function playAudio() {
  x.play();   
}
</script>
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: you cannot play audio files on page load, unless first you interact with the page (click, move mouse etc)

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Do you get an error?

Comment: Your code does work on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oc19z6g0/

Comment: @Nadir Abbas. I know the javascript code i have introduced contains a click event and before copying it to my blogger post, i tried it on w3schools and codepen websites and it worked fine. Kokodoko I do not get any errors. It just does not work. It works on jsfiddle.net the link you provided.

Answer (score 0):

You need to work with speechSynthesis
to convert text to audio

like so

```
var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
msg.text = "Hello World";
window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg); 


//if you want speak with selected text you can do so 

function speakSelection(event) {
  const selection = event.target.value.substring(event.target.selectionStart, event.target.selectionEnd);
  window.speechSynthesis.speak(`${selection}`) ;
}

document.onselect = speakSelection;
```

Comment: Thanks @Salem_Raouf, but this code did not work either. When i clicked on the highlighted word nothing happens.

Comment: @emg Yes of course what this code does is speak with Hello world str

Comment: @emg okey would you please mark it as right answer

Answer (score 0):

@Salem_Raouf I have in fact tried a different method and it worked. the code is down below.

```
<!--[ In the head section of the HTML ]-->

<!--audio-->

<script type="text/javascript">
function play_single_sound() {
document.getElementById('audiotag').play();
}
</script>

<!--/audio-->

<!--[ In the body section of the HTML ]-->

<!--embedded audio-->

<head>
<style>
div#audio {
display: none;
overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
</head>
<div id="audio">
<audio id="audiotag" src="audio link" autobuffer="autobuffer"></audio>
</div>
<!--/embedded audio-->
<!--button/link-->
<a href="javascript:play_single_sound();">Hyperlink</a>
<!--/button/link-->
```